# Can a condition be defined on timeout for WebDriverWait?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can a condition - examples of click on a button / driver.navigate.back() - be included on expiration of time units (timeout of WebDriverWait)?

Example: 
For the below statements - 
WebDriverWait wait60 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait60.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.locator)));

If the elementtobeclickable is not loaded on the webpage within the 60 seconds - I would like the statement driver.navigate.back() be executed. Any means of defining this type of statement (say at class level) so all wait60.until conditions lead to the same defined statement(s) on timeout?

Comment: You don't want to use try catch?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not included in the `WebDriverWait` functionality. I would probably use try-catch exception handling, and when you catch `timeoutException`, then call `driver.navigate.back()`

You can create a method that would do this and call it whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a try-catch block like this:

```
try{
    WebDriverWait wait60 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait60.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.locator)));
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Element not found in due time.  "+e.getMessage);
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

In case the element is not found in due time, an TimeoutException will be thrown and it will be subsequently handled in catch block. Also, after that the browser is navigated back.

Comment: TimeoutException will be thrown instead of NoSuchElementExeption. I have edited this.